# VBA SAP GUI Scripting with SAP Logon as different user

Tags: vba, ms-access, user-interface, sap-gui

I have a piece of Gui Scripting which opens a connection to a specific SAP system. This works fine as long as I open SAP Logon as the same user as the one that is logged into the machine.
However, I now need to open SAP Logon as a different user. So far so good, everything works if I do it manually, but in the Gui Scripting line

```
Set SAPGUIApp = GetObject("SAPGUI")
```

SAPGUIApp is not set correctly (it remains empty). Does anyone know how to fix this? Do I need to specify in which user context SAP Logon is running? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: `GetObject()` gets an instance of an existing `SAPGUI` class. This instance seems to be attached to the user's SAP Logon. I guessing that you might need to use  `CreateObject()` to create a new instance for your different user. This is a really specialist question.
Surely there are resources from SAP which can help guide you.

Comment: I'm a bit of a beginner regarding GUI Scripting... can you point me to some guides which are understandable and deal with these sort of problems?